# How to change default option for a Github repository through a workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github workflow in a template that configures a new repository after creating it from a template I have. One of the finals steps is to post a new PR after the configuration is done. That step looks like this, with some other things but this is the most minimal version of it I could whittle it down to:

```yaml
name: Create Project

on: create 


jobs:
  configure-project: 
    if: github.event.ref == github.event.master_branch # only happens on creation of master branch
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
    runs-on: "windows-latest"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
      - run: python3 ./.github/workflows/config-premake.py ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
        # steps:
      - uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
        with:
          commit-message: "Configuration of ${{ github.event.repository.name }} complete "
          title: Configure Repository
          body: | # Configuration PR
            Configured new repository using repo_name as ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          branch: config
```

My problem is that the `pull-requests: write` option does not do anything if the Settings -> Actions -> General -> 'Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests' is not set. Is there a way to override that so projects from this template all have that checked or even change that setting from the workflow so that I can successfully open the pull request with the configuration changes?

I've been reading the docs trying to find something about changing either template settings or how to change settings from workflows and have not found anything useful yet.